# Is there a way to stop time.sleep in windows?

Tags: python, windows

In *nix python signaling allows me to stop sleep before it is ready. Is there any similar mechanism available in windows -- seems that all the methods end up intercepting code only after the sleep?

Code example:

```
from time import sleep
.. do something that will intercept the sleep
try:
    sleep(60)
finally:
    print 'how to get here under 60 seconds in windows?'
```

Similar question that doesn't have an answer for windows:
[break/interrupt a time.sleep() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114292/break-interrupt-a-time-sleep-in-python)

Comment: Can you write your code so it's waiting on a `threading.Event`, with a timeout of 60s, and hit that event from another thread if you want to cancel the wait?

Comment: first read the sentence parsing classic punctuation. Wish there was a way to stop time by sleeping somewhere.

Comment: It is not my code. It is unkown client code that I am trying to stop after timeout has occurred. It seems that in cpython no really good mechanism exists.. and yeah we have also tried threads and subprocess is a no go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python documentation for `signal` says:

> • Although Python signal handlers are called asynchronously as far as
>   the Python user is concerned, they can only occur between the “atomic”
>   instructions of the Python interpreter. This means that signals
>   arriving during long calculations implemented purely in C (such as
>   regular expression matches on large bodies of text) may be delayed for
>   an arbitrary amount of time.

whereas `time` says:

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any
>   caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that
>   signal’s catching routine.

On Windows, apparently `time.sleep()` is not implemented in accordance with the documentation, because the handler for a signal received during sleep is not acted upon until the full duration of the sleep is finished. The following example:

```
import signal, time

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

print("signal set, sleeping")
time.sleep(10)
print("sleep done")
```

prints:

```
signal set, sleeping
Signal handler called with signal 2
sleep done
```

with the first line occurring immediately and the second two after 10 seconds, regardless of when the interrupt occurs.

As Thomas K suggests, a better strategy would be to use threads and synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will do it for you, but here's a little workaround you could do:

```
for i in range(60):
    if checkIfIShouldInterruptSleep():
         break
    time.sleep(1)
print "Finished Sleeping!"
```

It's only accurate to the second, but it might serve your purpose. Happy coding!