# python script fails running as a daemon (EOFError: EOF when reading a line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, launchd

I've created a python3 script that runs fine on command line but when I try to run as a daemon in MacosX gives error 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line'. Basically code is as follows:

```
  (...)

  def main():

    # Connect
    port, speed = connect_port()

    device = XBeeDevice(port, speed)

    try:
      device.open()
      # print("Waiting for data...\n")

     (...)

      device.add_packet_received_callback(packet_received_callback)
      input()

    finally:
      if device is not None and device.is_open():
        device.close()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

plist seems to be fine as script starts and runs once before to give error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/maslestorres.cat/jardiNet_datalogger.py", line 214, in <module>
main()
File "/maslestorres.cat/jardiNet_datalogger.py", line 206, in main
input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

So basically I don't know how to adapt the input() line to allow to run as a daemon. Python is version 3.7.2 and MacOSX is 10.8.5.

Comment: Please explain what you’re doing in more detail. What is the purpose of `input()` in your code? Does it wait for the user’s approval to resume operation? Typically the whole point of a daemon is to run continuously without user interaction.

Comment: input() function is just to ensure main never ends and callbacks are executed. Similar behavior can be obtained with a busy wait loop --> while True: pass but obviously this loop wastes CPU

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want your daemon to `device.open()` once and then wait for packets indefinitely, running `packet_received_callback` on each one?

Answer (score 2):

By its very nature, a daemon cannot [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) from the console. You need another way to suspend the main thread indefinitely while letting the XBee [`PacketListener` thread](https://github.com/digidotcom/python-xbee/blob/3297235a0419e35e83513ad11df8b707571daf4f/digi/xbee/devices.py#L1632) to keep running callbacks.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to replace `input()` with:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1000000)    # arbitrarily large number
```

When it’s time to shut down, your system’s service manager will stop your daemon:

- either by sending `SIGTERM` — in which case your daemon will terminate immediately, without executing the `finally` block;
- or by sending `SIGINT` — in which case a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception will bubble out of `time.sleep(1000000)`, and the `finally` block will run.

In either case, your process should stop quickly.

For a more correct solution, capable also of handling `SIGTERM` gracefully, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346184/200445