# Python script required multiple CTRL + C to stop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a scenario where I want to handle SIGINT int python to clean up some things and then exit.
I am using the following code.

```
import threading
import signal

def shutdown_handler(*args):
    raise SystemExit('Exiting')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)

def main():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("***")
    
sub_thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
sub_thread.start()
sub_thread.join()
```

But it requires me to press CTRL + c multiple times before the program exits.
The following works fine

```
import time
import threading
import signal

def shutdown_handler(*args):
    # Do some clean up here. 
    raise SystemExit('Exiting')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)

def main():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("***")
    
main()
```

I am using the first code, because of a suggestion on [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue5315) thread
Can you please tell me why this behaviour. Is it because of multiple threads running and how can I get around this?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at an alternative way to handle CTRL+C: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346184/1012381 . Which OS and python versions are you running?

Comment: I am running Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: And a look at this link, appears you need to catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If terminating program with one `Control-C` is your only requirement, set `daemon=True` in constructor.

```py
import threading
import signal

def shutdown_handler(*args):
    raise SystemExit('Exiting')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)

def main():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("***")
    
sub_thread = threading.Thread(target=main, daemon=True) # here
sub_thread.start()
sub_thread.join()
```