# how do I stop this while loop after a specific time?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm currently making a lightning code, but I have some problems with the while loop.
I want to stop the While loop after a specific time that I set.
here's the code.

```py
class Light:
    def __init__(self):
        self.work_flag = False

    def start(self):
        self.work_flag = True

    def stop(self):
        self.work_flag = False


    def mode_1(self):
        print("turn on red+green+blue light")
        sleep(0.5)
        while self.work_flag:
            print("turn on red light")
            sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on green light")
            sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on blue light")
            sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on red+green light")
            sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on red+blue light")
            sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on green+blue light")
            sleep(0.3)

light = Light()

def light_start():
    light.start()
    light.mode_1()

def light_stop():
    light.stop()

light_start()
sleep(5)
light_stop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [break/interrupt a time.sleep() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114292/break-interrupt-a-time-sleep-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should add elapsed_time method. It will wait until all the work is done in 'while' but I think it's not bad at all.

```
import time

class Light:
    def __init__(self):
        self.work_flag = False

    def start(self):
        self.startTime = time.time() # start time
        self.work_flag = True

    def stop(self):
        self.work_flag = False


    def mode_1(self):
        self.endTime = time.time() # end time
        elapsedTime = self.endTime - self.startTime # elapsed time
        print("turn on red+green+blue light")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
        #if elapsedTime > 5: the work is done.
        while self.work_flag and elapsedTime < 5: # 5 seconds
            self.endTime = time.time() # end time
            elapsedTime = self.endTime - self.startTime # elapsed time
            print(elapsedTime)
            print("turn on red light")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on green light")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on blue light")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on red+green light")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on red+blue light")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("turn on green+blue light")
            time.sleep(0.3)

light = Light()

def light_start():
    light.start()
    light.mode_1()

def light_stop():
    light.stop()

start = time.time()
light_start()
time.sleep(5)
light_stop()
```