# How to stop the sleep() function

Tags: python, time

I have an infinite loop that immediately goes to sleep for one minute and then displays a message, but the problem is that when I stop the loop, the sleep() function works and the message is displayed at the end. Is it possible to reset sleep() after stopping the loop immediately?

```
from time import sleep
i = int(input())
flag = True
while flag:
    if i < 0:
        flag = False
    sleep(60)
    print('Hello, world')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you interrupt that loop with Ctrl-C, the app will end immediately.  Perhaps you should show more of your actual code.

Comment: What do you mean by *stopping the loop*? There's no `break` there. And what does it mean to *reset* `sleep()`?

Comment: @JonathanCiapetti When the loop stops, the sleep() function should also stop, when I stop the loop, the sleep() function continues

Comment: How are you stopping the loop? Please post a [mre]

Comment: you arent actually stopping the loop ... if you were the sleep would not be active .... its hard to tell you much more without you posting a real snippet of your code

Comment: you most likely need to learn about threading, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114292/break-interrupt-a-time-sleep-in-python

Comment: I still dont think thats a snippet of your actual code... but if it is just change `flag=False` to `break;`

Comment: forgot to add `i -= 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will likely need to implement a "special interruptable sleep" ... something like this could be a naive implementation that "works"

```
def do_something():
    pass
    
class Program:
    flag = True
    def stoppable_sleep(self,t):
        endTime = time.time() + t
        while time.time() < endTime and self.flag:
             time.sleep(0.1)
    def mainloop(self):
        while flag:
            do_something()
            self.stoppable_sleep(60)
        print("Done...")
    def stop(self):
        self.flag = False

p = Program()
threading.Timer(5,p.stop)
p.mainloop()
```