# Make read object async

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have two threads: one of them writes into a datastructre and the other monitors for changes using a while True loop.

Writer thread (Socket):

```
if new_mess:
  datastruct.update(..)
```

Reader thread:

```
initial_state = datastruct.get_state()
while True:
   if datastruct.get_state() !=  initial_state:
       do_sth()
```

The problem is that the reader blocks the writer, resulting in poor performance on the writer side. I would like to create a coroutine on the method datastruct.curr_state so it doesn't block the writer. However, I am not sure how the `await` condition should be structured.

Datastruct class:

```
class Datastruct:
  ...
  async def get_state(self, key):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return self.elements.get(key)
  ...
```

The above method gives cedes the execution context and then the event loop moves ahead with other awaiting tasks. Clearly, this is not a good approach since the coroutine waits until the sleep useless function is executed.

At this point, you may have realized that I'm completely new to `asyncio`. Idk if there is an easier way of doing this non-blocking read. Any help will be greatly welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Is `elements` a dictionary? There's no I/O involved in doing that lookup so it doesn't really make sense to make `get_state` awaitable. It might make more sense to add the sleep to your while loop. If you're concerned about the duration, an [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) or [Condition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Condition) might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads to read/write concurrently on the same class instance is a bad idea due to race conditions..

Did you try using a `threading.Lock` with your threads to protect `Datastruct` access?

On the other hand, with `asyncio` if `self.elements.get(key)` is synchronous you won't get any benefits..

To fix this, you need to implement an asychronous version of `get` to use it like

```py
return await self.elements.get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346184/11494333

Also, kudos for @dirn for suggesting the use of Events.