# Why doesn't this Python keyboard interrupt work? (in PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, try-except, keyboardinterrupt

My Python try/except loop does not seem to trigger a keyboard interrupt when Ctrl + C is pressed while debugging my code in PyCharm. (The same issue occurs when using Ctrl + C while running the program, but not in the PyCharm Python console.)

My code look like this:

```py
try:
    while loop:
        print("busy")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

The full code can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/shardros/61901ba8a70caf0a12b00b3a61b2a88e). The code above produces the same error.

Comment: Your posted code has a bug (x is not defined) and when I add `x = 2` it prints "Doing Stuff" until I press ctrl-c, then it exits. I can't reproduce your problem on linux.

Comment: The new code still works when run from the shell.

Comment: When running from shell I get `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your screen shot it appears that you are running this code in an IDE. The thing about IDEs is that they are not quite the same as running normally, especially when it comes to handling of keyboard characters. The way you press ctrl-c, your IDE thinks you want to copy text. The python program never sees the character. Pehaps it brings up a separate window when running? Then you would select that window before ctrl-c.

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to use this question: the keyboard interrupt shortcut in pycharm is Ctrl + F2

Comment: No, Ctrl-F2 is equivalent to pressing the PyCharm 'stop' button. This doesn't send a keyboard interrupt - so your process will simply stop, rather than exiting via any necessary cleanup.

Comment: In recent versions of PyCharm, you can enable `Emulate terminal in output console` in your Run Configuration - this allows Ctrl + C in the Run console to send a keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Emulate terminal in output console does seem to work in this case, but I have to hit 'enter' after ctrl^c, so it's not quite the same as on the command line. Unfortunately it does not seem to work reliably in other cases. I don't have a simple one to share, but it seems that ctrl c has no effect on my script. Not sure why.

Comment: @ChristopherGurnee Thank you for that. I've been dealing with improperly terminating threads as a result of Pycharm's "stop" button since I couldn't figure out how to get SIGINT in there.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem and think there's an easier solution:

In PyCharm go to "Run"/"Edit Configurations" and check "Emulate terminal in output console".
PyCharm now accepts keyboard interrupts (make sure the console is focused).

Tested on:
PyCharm 2019.1 (Community Edition)

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm's Python Console raises the exception `console_thrift.KeyboardInterruptException` on Ctrl-C instead of `KeyboardInterrupt`. The exception `console_thrift.KeyboardInterruptException` is not a subclass of `KeyboardInterrupt`, therefore not caught by the line `except KeyboardInterrupt`.

Adding the following lines would make your script compatible with PyCharm.

```
try:
    from console_thrift import KeyboardInterruptException as KeyboardInterrupt
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This would not break compatibility with running the script in a terminal, or other IDE, like IDLE or Spyder, since the module `console_thrift` is found only within PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

If that comment doesn't solve your problem, (from  @tdelaney) you need to have your shell window focused (meaning you've clicked on it when the program is running.) and then you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: I have however all that does is highlight the printed statement. See this: http://imgur.com/M43LPuu

Comment: @Edwinthebreadwin - let us know what IDE you are using. Its likely intercepting ctrl-c and doing something else.... like copying!

Comment: I'm using pycharm community edition but I have just run it in IDLE and that doesn't work either imgur.com/a/ZKAus

Comment: Yes it is copying, any idea how to stop this?

Comment: Ignoring the accepted answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913490/keyboard-interrupt-in-debug-mode-pycharm, the other answer says that you just press the STOP button. I don't have pycharm and can't test.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PyCharm's Python console and use Ctrl + C, if you catch the exception that PyCharm raises when Ctrl + C is pressed. I wrote a short function below called `is_keyboard_interrupt` that tells you whether the exception is KeyboardInterrupt, including PyCharm's. If it is not, simply re-raise it. I paste a simplified version of the code below.

When it is run:

- type 'help' and press Enter to repeat the loop.
- type anything else and press Enter to check that ValueError is handled properly.
- Press Ctrl + C to check that KeyboardInterrupt is caught, including in PyCharm's python console.

Note: This doesn't work with PyCharm's debugger console (the one invoked by "Debug" rather than "Run"), but there the need for Ctrl + C is less because you can simply press the pause button.

I also put this on my Gist where I may make updates: https://gist.github.com/yulkang/14da861b271576a9eb1fa0f905351b97

```py
def is_keyboard_interrupt(exception):
    # The second condition is necessary for it to work with the stop button
    # in PyCharm Python console.
    return (type(exception) is KeyboardInterrupt
            or type(exception).__name__ == 'KeyboardInterruptException')

try:
    def print_help():
        print("To exit type exit or Ctrl + c can be used at any time")
    print_help()

    while True:
        task = input("What do you want to do? Type \"help\" for help:- ")
        if task == 'help':
            print_help()
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")

            # to check that ValueError is handled separately
            raise ValueError()

except Exception as ex:
    try:
        # Catch all exceptions and test if it is KeyboardInterrupt, native or
        # PyCharm's.
        if not is_keyboard_interrupt(ex):
            raise ex

        print('KeyboardInterrupt caught as expected.')
        print('Exception type: %s' % type(ex).__name__)
        exit()

    except ValueError:
        print('ValueError!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working normally, since i put a variable "x" in your code and i use *tabs* instead *spaces*.

```
try:

    def help():
        print("Help.")

    def doStuff():
        print("Doing Stuff")

    while True:
        x = int(input())
        if x == 1:
            help()
        elif x == 2:
            doStuff()
        else:
            exit()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **shift + control + C**. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the window is selected when you press ctrl+c. I just ran your program in IDLE and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @Edwinthebreadwin your `except` statement is indented too far over. The `try:` and `except:` statements need to be indented equally in order for them to work properly. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason if <Strg+C> does not stop the program:

When a text is marked in the shell, <Strg+C> is interpreted as "copy the marked text to clipboard".

Just unmark the text and press <Strg+C> again.