# Why While True loop does not interrupt by `KeyboardInterrupt` on Pycharm?

Tags: python, while-loop, pycharm, try-catch, interrupt

I want to interrupt my `while True` loop in below code but it does not work:

```
try:  
    while True:  
        print(1)    
except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    print('interrupted!')  
    exit()
```

I am running this code in PyCharm. Why isn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> triggering `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a while loop with a keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180941/how-to-kill-a-while-loop-with-a-keystroke)

Comment: That code works for me.

Comment: It is not same I checked several similar questions

Comment: What operating system are you using? And how are you running that code? Clearly it works for many people, including me. I'm running it on Linux via bash.

Comment: should I import any special library or module?

Comment: Why would you think you need to import a module? Are you getting an error message? What does "not working" mean? _Please_ (a) read [ask] and (b) answer the questions we're asking you.

Comment: I am using Windows10 and Pycharm and run the code by Pycharm also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39796689/354577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PyCharm [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is bound to "copy"](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf). Try [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stopping-and-pausing-applications.html) instead.

Comment: The documentation this links to appears to be up to date, @Chiel. What OS are you on?

Comment: I am currently on Windows 10. Ctrl + F2 does terminate the program, but it does not trigger a KeyboardInterrupt exception.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pressing Ctrl+C, because that's the correct way of causing `KeyboardInterrupt`

As @Chris mentioned it won't work for pycharm. Try using Ctrl+F2 for that

Comment: I tried 'Ctrl+C','Ctrl+X','Delete','Esc' and none of them works.