# Stop a while loop by escape key?

Tags: python, opencv

I edited my question because  now when i ran my code outside Pycharm (IN Powershell) the keyboard interrupt works fine but now i am struggling to terminate the code on Escape key press.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

def record_screen():

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('ResultFile.avi', fourcc, 25.0, screensize)

    while True:
        try:
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img_np = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
            print('recording....')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


record_screen()
```

Comment: Why not use Ctrl+C? (this would raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`)

Comment: can you demontstate how ?

Comment: i was trying to use escape key to terminate the recording but it simply won't terminate the loop

Comment: Whenever a program is running and the user presses Ctrl+C, a `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised. Try this in a Python IDE: `while True: print(1)`. Press enter, wait a few seconds, then press Ctrl+C and see what happens.

Comment: nope it didn't help

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: i am using Pycharm  as my IDE

Comment: after i finish recording say an excel file i go back to the IDE using ctrl+tab and press escape key but , the loop doesen't terminate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796689/why-doesnt-this-python-keyboard-interrupt-work-in-pycharm/39796898

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's pretty difficult to listen for keypresses unless you expect one for *every* iteration of your loop, which for what you're doing is impractical. I think Joel has it right in the comments, you should be using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

and catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` like this

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

def record_screen():

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('ResultFile.avi', fourcc, 25.0, screensize)

    while True:
        try:
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img_np = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
            print('recording....')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


record_screen()
```

This way, the `KeyboardInterrupt` won't terminate the program, it'll just end the while loop, allowing you to release your writer and cleanup the rest of the `cv2` resources.

Because you're using PyCharm as your IDE, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> might not work for you - try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> instead.

Comment: i tried using the above solution but the loop didn't terminate after i pressed ctrl+c

Comment: I've updated my answer for you because you use PyCharm, use ctrl+f2

Comment: i just used ctrl+f2 key but the loop still didn't terminate

Comment: Can't figure out the reason for this

Comment: and here is another problem if i use cv2.imshow('Screen', frame) just before out.write(frame) and then run my program i am able to stop the recording by pressing the escape key

Comment: but the downside of it is that every time the program starts the screen is bombarded with frames

Comment: @Carl what about this - don't put the `cv2.imshow('Screen', frame)` in the while loop, put it just before - then does it work? If you put it in the loop, it'll create a frame for each iteration, but if you put it before, it should only create one

Answer (score 0):

You should make a variable called running! Set 'running = True' before the while loop. And instead of the while loop being 'while True:', make it 'while running = True:'. Finally, in the while loop, if you hit ESC, set 'running = False'

Here is an example with pygame:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def record():

    # init
    running = True

    while running == True:

        # record

        events = pygame.event.get()

        for event in events:

            if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:

                running = False

    quit()

record()
```

Comment: What on Earth? Where has `pygame` come from? This is not a good solution.

Comment: and it didn't helped

Comment: i tried the answer but the loop still ran despite pressing escape key