# KeyboardInterrupt Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, keyboardinterrupt

I'm having a hard time handling Exceptions in pycharm 3.8:

When I press ctrl+c running my program, it doesn't work, so I've been told to use pycharm console to test it, and it does work, interrupting the keyboard input.

```
def readFloat(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(f'{msg}'))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print(f'\033[31mError. Not valid.\033[m')
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\033[31mYou didn\'t type a number.\033[m')
            return 0


b = readFloat('Your Number: ')
print(f'\nThat\'s your number: {b}')
```

But now, when I try to Control+C, it doesn't catch my except and print my custom error report, returning 0. It gives me some huge and red error lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Curso/Aula 23/ex113.py", line 35, in <module>
    b = readFloat('Your Number: ')
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Curso/Aula 23/ex113.py", line 26, in readFloat
    return float(input(f'{msg}'))
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_stdin.py", line 64, in readline
    requested_input = self.rpc_client.requestInput()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 226, in _req
    return super(TSyncClient, self)._req(_api, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 160, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 192, in _recv
    raise v
console_thrift.KeyboardInterruptException: KeyboardInterruptException()
```

So I tried to add a generic exception just to print the error class, and I got this:

```
Error found: <class 'console_thrift.KeyboardInterruptException'>
```

So I can't manage to detect an except *keyboardInterrupt* and work with it, just using a generic exception, any ideas?

**Edit**

The only plugin that I added was a Theme UI to run pycharm totally black, the rest of them came with the instalation, I think. I ran the .py file using CMD and it works just fine, detecting the keyboard interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    from console_thrift import KeyboardInterruptException as KeyboardInterrupt
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Ref: [Why doesn't this python keyboard interrupt work? (in pycharm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796689/why-doesnt-this-python-keyboard-interrupt-work-in-pycharm)

The thing about IDEs is that they are not quite the same as running normally, especially when it comes to handling of keyboard characters. The way you press ctrl-c, your IDE thinks you want to copy text. The python program never sees the character. Perhaps it brings up a separate window when running? Then you would select that window before ctrl-c.

Comment: Sorry, I thought giving reference is enough. Also I am not aware of how to mark an answer as duplicate.I will check on that from here on. Thanks.

Comment: Providing a link does avoid plagiarism, ya, but it's better, and is site policy, to point people to existing answers instead of copying-and-pasting the same data all over the place. Under the question, you can click `close`->`duplicate`->Then provide the link that you believe answers the question.

Comment: is there any minimum Reputation points before you get these options?

Comment: I thought it was 500, but it may be higher. In a case like that then, until you have the ability, you can post a link in the question suggesting the dupe, and someone with the ability can close it on your behalf.

Comment: Close voting requires 3000 reputation, but you can flag as a duplicate once you have 50 reputation.